# How to access state values by index in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, jsx

I'm struggling to access values inside a state in React using axios and my code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    moviedata:null
  }

  getMovies(){
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/movies/")
      .then(moviedata => {
        this.setState({
          moviedata: moviedata.data    
        });
      })
      .then(x => { console.log(this.state.moviedata)});
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getMovies();
  }

  render () {
    return <h1>Movie Examples include </h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

The console.log looks like this:

```
0: {title: "Terminator 2: Judgement Day", plot: "Rise of the machines.", year: 1991}
1: {title: "The Italian Job", plot: "A comic hinging on a traffic jam", year: 1969}
```

How can I include the title of the first entry, i.e. 'Terminator 2: Judgement Day',  inside the h1 tag, after the word 'include'?

I tried:

```
render () {
  return <h1>Movie Examples include {this.state.moviedata[0].title}</h1>
}
```

and got an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moviedata` in your component state is initially `null`, so trying to access `[0]` from that will give rise to your error.

You could e.g. return early from the render method until `moviedata` has been set.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    const { moviedata } = this.state;

    if (moviedata === null) {
      return null;
    }
    return <h1>Movie Examples include {moviedata[0].title}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I'm still a beginner so really happy of the simplicity in your answer:)

Comment: So does the render function keep looping until `moviedata` is set before continuing to the `return` statement ?

Comment: @West Great! You're welcome. A component is re-rendered when the state or props changes, so the render method will be run once before your data is loaded, and then once again when you use `setState` in the axios callback.

Comment: Understood! Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to "know" that the component is in a "loading" state. Without that, your state data is undefined (Still loading)

Here's how to do it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    moviedata:null,
    isLoading: true
  }

  getMovies(){
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/movies/")
      .then(moviedata => {
        this.setState({
          moviedata: moviedata.data,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .then(x => { console.log(this.state.moviedata)});
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getMovies();
  }

  render () {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <h1>Please wait...</h1>
    }

    // show only the first movie
    return <h1>Movie #1 {this.state.moviedata[0].title}</h1>;

    // show all the movies
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.moviedata.map((m, idx) => <h1 key={idx}>Movie: {m.title}</h1>}
      </>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will look into this. I'm still new to React so not sure at the moment how to properly include your last return statement in my case

Comment: In my example I'm showing all the movies. I'll add an example to show only the first movie.

Comment: Okay great I get your example now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to account for the fact that the Axios request is asynchronous, so the component may render before the data are loaded. For example:

```
render () {
  const data = this.state.moviedata;
  return <h1>Movie Examples include {data ? data[0].title : ""}</h1>
}
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing got displayed after 'include'